# Import Visual c++ project to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-c++

I have one visual c++ solution(project) that is written on visual studio 2010.

I want to import that project to Eclipse (JUNO) as c++ project and see the execution.

Can somebody tell me step by step what is the possible solution for this?

I have seen example from [IBM Help](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-vscdt/) but that was not helpful. Somebody please explain with a hello world project.

Comment: I have several projects that I build sometmes with Visual Studio and sometimes with Eclipse CDT but I need to maintain build files for both products separately. I don't know of any importer that creates CDT build files from VS project files. You would have to set up CDT settings manually. What information do you need exactly?

Comment: OMG. I didn't look at the date of this question. I guess you have what you need in the meantime - or you don't need it anymore. Sorry.